# Any helpful math book?

Tags: integration

I'm trying to become an Applied Math major. But I am not doing well in math. I understand the concepts up to Calc II and I'm starting to have trouble on Calc III. I know I need more practice on Calc II, so I wanted to ask for some recommendations on those Math books. The James Stewart textbook is kinda helpful tho, wordy. Are there any books that have more practice problems and also show the answers step by step? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Calculus 2 and 3, I'd suggest anything by Ron Larson. I haven't seen Stewart's books, but I've heard good things. I'd also suggest [Paul's math notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/) as a place to find help and practice problems with steps. Another great place for lots of help and guidelines is [MIT's free course resources and lectures](https://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Schaum's outlines, forever and always for anything computational. For your purposes, the calculus one is more than enough.